# Get SKProduct from SKProductsRequest

Tags: objective-c, in-app-purchase, sprite-kit, skproduct

Hi i'm trying to add an in App purchase to my App but every Time i call the method "buy" i get an error "Invalid product identifier: (null)". 
How can i call the method without getting these error / How can i make the product inside the buy method the same as the product in the response?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *productIdentifiers = @[@"product1"];   
}

- (void)fetchProducts {
    NSSet *identifierSet = [NSSet setWithArray:productIdentifier];
    SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers: identifierSet];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
}

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"Inside productsRequest");
    for(SKProduct *product in response.products) {
        NSLog(@"%@", product);
    }
}

- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
}

-(void)unlock {
    SKProduct *product = [[SKProduct alloc] init];
    [self buy:product];
}


- (void)buy:(SKProduct *)product {
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}


- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for(SKPaymentTransaction *tx in transactions) {
        switch(tx.transactionState) {

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                NSLog(@"Unlock %@", tx.payment.productIdentifier);
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:tx];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", tx.error);
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:tx];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                NSLog(@"Unlock %@", tx.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier);
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:tx];
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set up these products in iTunesConnect with the same product IDs?

Comment: yes i have set these products up..

Comment: There seems to be no connection betwen your unlock method and the products returned by productsRequest:. It seems you now are buying an effectively unitalized product. Have you tried using then products returned by productsRequest: in your unlock method?

Comment: I tried to but i could not manage it.. How can i get these products? Thx

Comment: The product identifier names will have to be exactly as you set them up in iTunesConnect. Not like "Product1", but more like "com.companyname.appname.productname"